# R - How to ensure TCP port is unused before connecting?

Tags: r, sockets

I'm using a [`socketConnection`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) which takes the TCP port number `port` as a mandatory parameter. Now, how can I ensure that I specify an **unused** port for `port` (my process is the server)?

**Edits:**

I know that you can specify `port = 0` so that the system allocates the port for you, but I have no means of subsequently finding out which port I was given.

Moreover, `socketConnection(..., server = T)` is blocking until the client process connects. But the client process doesn't know which port to connect to because the server process is being blocked and isn't able to determine the port number it got assigned. Catch 22!

Comment: Most systems will return an error if you try to use a port that is already bound to something.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you're creating a client socket or a server socket.

- If you're creating a client socket, the port parameter species the *target* port. So it must be a port that *is* in use, as a server, otherwise you will get a connection refusal.
- If you're creating a server socket, normally you will want a fixed port number, and if it's already in use it means your server is already running. If you want a random system-allocated port number for a server, and you have some other means of telling the clients what the port number is, just specify zero.

Comment: Thanks - updated my question to reflect your points. My process is the server. Passing `port = 0` seems ideal, except that I have no idea how I can subsequently discover which port I was allocated. This information is crucual for the client process to know which port to connect to.

Comment: There should be a method in the object returned by socketConnection() for that.

Comment: Thanks, but `socketConnection(..., server = T)` is blocking until the client process connects. But the client process doesn't know which port to connect to because the server process is being blocked and isn't able to determine the port number it got assigned. Catch 22!